# The most elegant way to generate permutations in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permutation

Given a the following table:

```
Index | Element
---------------
  1   |    A
  2   |    B
  3   |    C
  4   |    D
```

We want to generate all the possible permutations (without repetitions) using the elements.
the final result (skipping some rows) will look like this:

```
  Results
----------
   ABCD
   ABDC
   ACBD
   ACDB
   ADAC
   ADCA

   ...

   DABC
   DACB
   DBCA
   DBAC
   DCAB
   DCBA

  (24 Rows)
```

**How would you do it?**

Comment: Don't tag it `[code-golf]` if it isn't a [code-golf](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-golf/info).

Comment: And application for PROLOG... I NEVER thought I would see the day

Comment: Here's an example that uses dynamic SQL: [Generating Permutations in T-SQL](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/generatingpermutationsintsql/2076/). NOTE: Free registration on [SQLServerCentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/) is required to view the article.

Comment: When the order of the items queried is critical to the results, SQL queries are never, IMHO, "elegant"

Comment: @Philip: hahahhaha yes. it's almost a tradeoff : ). but the real question would be: there is another alternative you could imagine, one most effective than a recursive CTE?

Comment: @SDReyes, no, not really. Besides being order-dependant (which breaks many set-based programming tricks), it is also a tough string manipulation problem, and SQL sucks at that too.


I honestly think writing conventional loops in procedural code would be the most effective way to do this.

Comment: (How big does the problem set get? 4 characters, 10, 26, N?)

Comment: In the sample results, you have, `ADAC` and `ADCA`, should be `ADBC` and `ADCB`

Comment: `charindex(Id+';',Ids) = 0` is more elegant than `Ids Not like '%'+Id+';%'`, IMO. Add a leading `;` to the anchor, and you can use the more robust `charindex(';'+Id+';',Ids) = 0`.

Comment: I think that for this kind of problems SQL have CLR Procs, and maybe You should considered to use one for this problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After making some perhaps snarky comments, this problem stuck in my brain all evening, and I eventually came up with the following set-based approach. I believe it definitely qualifies as "elegant", but then  I also think it qualifies as "kinda dumb".  You make the call.

First, set up some tables:

```
--  For testing purposes
DROP TABLE Source
DROP TABLE Numbers
DROP TABLE Results


--  Add as many rows as need be processed--though note that you get N! (number of rows, factorial) results,
--  and that gets big fast. The Identity column must start at 1, or the algorithm will have to be adjusted.
--  Element could be more than char(1), though the algorithm would have to be adjusted again, and each element
--  must be the same length.
CREATE TABLE Source
 (
   SourceId  int      not null  identity(1,1)
  ,Element   char(1)  not null
 )

INSERT Source (Element) values ('A')
INSERT Source (Element) values ('B')
INSERT Source (Element) values ('C')
INSERT Source (Element) values ('D')
--INSERT Source (Element) values ('E')
--INSERT Source (Element) values ('F')


--  This is a standard Tally table (or "table of numbers")
--  It only needs to be as long as there are elements in table Source
CREATE TABLE Numbers (Number int not null)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (1)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (2)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (3)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (4)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (5)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (6)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (7)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (8)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (9)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (10)


--  Results are iteratively built here. This could be a temp table. An index on "Length" might make runs
--  faster for large sets.  Combo must be at least as long as there are characters to be permuted.
CREATE TABLE Results
 (
   Combo   varchar(10)  not null
  ,Length  int          not null
 )
```

Here's the routine:

```
SET NOCOUNT on

DECLARE
  @Loop     int
 ,@MaxLoop  int


--  How many elements there are to process
SELECT @MaxLoop = max(SourceId)
 from Source


--  Initialize first value
TRUNCATE TABLE Results
INSERT Results (Combo, Length)
 select Element, 1
  from Source
  where SourceId = 1

SET @Loop = 2

--  Iterate to add each element after the first
WHILE @Loop <= @MaxLoop
 BEGIN

    --  See comments below. Note that the "distinct" remove duplicates, if a given value
    --  is to be included more than once
    INSERT Results (Combo, Length)
     select distinct
        left(re.Combo, @Loop - nm.Number)
        + so.Element
        + right(re.Combo, nm.Number - 1)
       ,@Loop
      from Results re
       inner join Numbers nm
        on nm.Number <= @Loop
       inner join Source so
        on so.SourceId = @Loop
      where re.Length = @Loop - 1

    --  For performance, add this in if sets will be large
    --DELETE Results
    -- where Length <> @Loop

    SET @Loop = @Loop + 1
 END

--  Show results
SELECT *
 from Results
 where Length = @MaxLoop
 order by Combo
```

The general idea is: when adding a new element (say "B") to any string (say, "A"), to catch all permutations you would add B
to all possible positions (Ba, aB), resulting in a new set of strings. Then iterate: Add a new element (C) to each position in a string
(AB becomes Cab, aCb, abC), for all strings (Cba, bCa, baC), and you have the set of permutations. Iterate over each result set with
the next character until you run out of characters... or resources. 10 elements is 3.6 million permutations, roughly 48MB with the above algorithm, and 14 (unique) elements would hit 87 billion permutations and 1.163 terabytes.

I'm sure it could eventually be wedged into a CTE, but in the end all that would be is a glorified loop. The logic
is clearer this way, and I can't help but think the CTE execution plan would be a nightmare.

Comment: It is set-based, and uses a bare minimum of string manipulation.

Comment: We need to stress test it against the cte solution to evaluate its merit in the optimization department.

Comment: stress test of 'abcdefghi':
your solution took 24 seconds to complete
'the answer' took 2 minutes
AlexKuznetsov's solution took 1 minute and 25 seconds
So... you win!

Comment: Marked as new Answer. Thanks Denis : ) +1

Answer (score 9):

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(5);
SET @s = 'ABCDE';

WITH Subsets AS (
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@s, Number, 1) AS VARCHAR(5)) AS Token,
CAST('.'+CAST(Number AS CHAR(1))+'.' AS VARCHAR(11)) AS Permutation,
CAST(1 AS INT) AS Iteration
FROM dbo.Numbers WHERE Number BETWEEN 1 AND 5
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(Token+SUBSTRING(@s, Number, 1) AS VARCHAR(5)) AS Token,
CAST(Permutation+CAST(Number AS CHAR(1))+'.' AS VARCHAR(11)) AS
Permutation,
s.Iteration + 1 AS Iteration
FROM Subsets s JOIN dbo.Numbers n ON s.Permutation NOT LIKE
'%.'+CAST(Number AS CHAR(1))+'.%' AND s.Iteration < 5 AND Number
BETWEEN 1 AND 5
--AND s.Iteration = (SELECT MAX(Iteration) FROM Subsets)
)
SELECT * FROM Subsets
WHERE Iteration = 5
ORDER BY Permutation

Token Permutation Iteration
----- ----------- -----------
ABCDE .1.2.3.4.5. 5
ABCED .1.2.3.5.4. 5
ABDCE .1.2.4.3.5. 5
(snip)
EDBCA .5.4.2.3.1. 5
EDCAB .5.4.3.1.2. 5
EDCBA .5.4.3.2.1. 5
```

first posted a while ago [here](http://sqlserver-tips.blogspot.com/2007/07/all-permutations-for-string.html)

However, it  would be better to do it in a better language such as C# or C++.

Comment: Thank you Alex. this is virtually the same approach. it uses recursive CTEs and a column (permutation) to remove duplicate elements from permutations

Comment: UPDATE: I think that a solution using native SQL would have better performance than one using C# integration. what do you think?

Comment: @SDReyes: at the time of this writing recursive CTEs are slow.

Comment: OK. that's new for me :). I think make some bencharking using C# and the recursive CTE is fair. maybe I can do some tests this weekend. thank you Alex! +1

Answer (score 9):

Just using SQL, without any code, you could do it if you can crowbar yourself another column into the table. Clearly you need to have one joined table for each of the values to be permuted.

```
with llb as (
  select 'A' as col,1 as cnt union 
  select 'B' as col,3 as cnt union 
  select 'C' as col,9 as cnt union 
  select 'D' as col,27 as cnt
) 
select a1.col,a2.col,a3.col,a4.col
from llb a1
cross join llb a2
cross join llb a3
cross join llb a4
where a1.cnt + a2.cnt + a3.cnt + a4.cnt = 40
```

Comment: NIce. is there any reason why you chose 1,3,9,7 and not 1,2,3,4, ?  Oh I see- reminds a base 3 flags where only 1 option is the right one. could be 1,2,4,8 ...no ?

Answer (score 2):

Am I correctly understanding that you built Cartesian product n x n x n x n, and then filter out unwanted stuff? The alternative would be generating all the numbers up to n! and then using [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) to map them via element encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than a recursive CTE:

```
declare @Number Table( Element varchar(MAX), Id varchar(MAX) )
Insert Into @Number Values ( 'A', '01')
Insert Into @Number Values ( 'B', '02')
Insert Into @Number Values ( 'C', '03')
Insert Into @Number Values ( 'D', '04')

select a.Element, b.Element, c.Element, d.Element
from @Number a
join @Number b on b.Element not in (a.Element)
join @Number c on c.Element not in (a.Element, b.Element)
join @Number d on d.Element not in (a.Element, b.Element, c.Element)
order by 1, 2, 3, 4
```

For an arbitrary number of elements, script it out:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#number') is not null drop table #number
create table #number (Element char(1), Id int, Alias as '_'+convert(varchar,Id))
insert #number values ('A', 1)
insert #number values ('B', 2)
insert #number values ('C', 3)
insert #number values ('D', 4)
insert #number values ('E', 5)

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = '
select '+stuff((
  select char(13)+char(10)+'+'+Alias+'.Element'
  from #number order by Id for xml path (''), type
  ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),3,1,' ')

set @sql += '
from #number '+(select top 1 Alias from #number order by Id)

set @sql += (
  select char(13)+char(10)+'join #number '+Alias+' on '+Alias+'.Id not in ('
    +stuff((
      select ', '+Alias+'.Id'
      from #number b where a.Id > b.Id
      order by Id for xml path ('')
      ),1,2,'')
    + ')'
  from #number a where Id > (select min(Id) from #number)
  order by Element for xml path (''), type
  ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')

set @sql += '
order by 1'

print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

To generate this:

```
select 
 _1.Element
+_2.Element
+_3.Element
+_4.Element
+_5.Element
from #number _1
join #number _2 on _2.Id not in (_1.Id)
join #number _3 on _3.Id not in (_1.Id, _2.Id)
join #number _4 on _4.Id not in (_1.Id, _2.Id, _3.Id)
join #number _5 on _5.Id not in (_1.Id, _2.Id, _3.Id, _4.Id)
order by 1
```

Comment: It doesn't work if you have repeating elements in the original table.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses a binary mask to select the correct rows:

```
;with src(t,n,p) as (
select element, index, power(2,index-1)
from table
)
select s1.t+s2.t+s3.t+s4.t
from src s1, src s2, src s3, src s4
where s1.p+s2.p+s3.p+s4.p=power(2,4)-1
```

My original post:

```
declare @t varchar(4) = 'ABCD'

;with src(t,n,p) as (
select substring(@t,1,1),1,power(2,0)
union all
select substring(@t,n+1,1),n+1,power(2,n)
from src
where n < len(@t)
)
select s1.t+s2.t+s3.t+s4.t
from src s1, src s2, src s3, src s4
where s1.p+s2.p+s3.p+s4.p=power(2,len(@t))-1
```

This is one of those problems that haunts you. I liked the simplicity of my original answer but there was this issue where I was still building all the possible solutions and then selecting the correct ones.  One more try to make this process more efficient by only building the solutions that were correct yielded this answer.  Add a character to the string only if that character didn't exist in the string.  Patindex seemed like the perfect companion for a CTE solution.  Here it is.

```
declare @t varchar(10) = 'ABCDEFGHIJ'

;with s(t,n) as (
select substring(@t,1,1),1
union all
select substring(@t,n+1,1),n+1
from s where n<len(@t)
)
,j(t) as (
select cast(t as varchar(10)) from s
union all
select cast(j.t+s.t as varchar(10))
from j,s where patindex('%'+s.t+'%',j.t)=0
)
select t from j where len(t)=len(@t)
```

I was able to build all 3.6 million solutions in 3 minutes and 2 seconds. Hopefully this solution will not get missed just because it's not the first.

Answer (score 0):

Current solution using a recursive CTE.

```
-- The base elements
Declare @Number Table( Element varchar(MAX), Id varchar(MAX) )
Insert Into @Number Values ( 'A', '01')
Insert Into @Number Values ( 'B', '02')
Insert Into @Number Values ( 'C', '03')
Insert Into @Number Values ( 'D', '04')

-- Number of elements
Declare @ElementsNumber int
Select  @ElementsNumber = COUNT(*)
From    @Number;



-- Permute!
With Permutations(   Permutation,   -- The permutation generated
                     Ids,            -- Which elements where used in the permutation
                     Depth )         -- The permutation length
As
(
    Select  Element,
            Id + ';',
            Depth = 1
    From    @Number
    Union All
    Select  Permutation + ' ' + Element,
            Ids + Id + ';',
            Depth = Depth + 1
    From    Permutations,
            @Number
    Where   Depth < @ElementsNumber And -- Generate only the required permutation number
            Ids Not like '%' + Id + ';%' -- Do not repeat elements in the permutation (this is the reason why we need the 'Ids' column) 
)
Select  Permutation
From    Permutations
Where   Depth = @ElementsNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is named Elements and has 4 rows, this is as simple as:

```
select e1.Element + e2.Element + e3.Element + e4.Element
from Elements e1
    join Elements e2 on e2.Element != e1.Element 
    join Elements e3 on e3.Element != e2.Element AND e3.Element != e1.Element 
    join Elements e4 on e4.Element != e3.Element AND e4.Element != e2.Element AND e4.Element != e1.Element
```

Answer (score 0):

Way too much rust on my SQL skills, but i took a different tack for a similar problem and thought it worth sharing.

```
Table1 - X strings in a single field Uno
Table2 - Y strings in a single field Dos

(SELECT Uno, Dos
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2 ON 1=1)
    UNION
(SELECT  Dos, Uno
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2 ON 1=1)
```

Same principle for 3 tables with an added CROSS JOIN

```
(SELECT  Tres, Uno, Dos
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2 ON 1=1
    CROSS JOIN Table3 ON 1=1)
```

although it takes 6 cross-join sets in the union.

Answer (score 0):

--Hopefully this is a quick solution, just change the values going into #X

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#X', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #X; CREATE table #X([Opt] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL)
Insert into #X values('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
declare @pSQL NVarChar(max)='select * from #X X1 ', @pN int =(select count(*) from #X), @pC int = 0;
while @pC<@pN begin
if @pC>0 set  @pSQL = concat(@pSQL,' cross join #X X', @pC+1);
set @pC = @pC +1;
end
execute(@pSQL)
```

--or as single column result

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#X', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #X; CREATE table #X([Opt] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL)
Insert into #X values('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
declare @pSQL NVarChar(max)=' as R from #X X1 ',@pSelect NVarChar(Max)=' ',@pJoin NVarChar(Max)='', @pN int =(select count(*) from #X), @pC int = 0;
while @pC<@pN begin
if @pC>0 set  @pJoin = concat(@pJoin ,' cross join #X X', @pC+1) set @pSelect =  concat(@pSelect ,'+ X', @pC+1,'.Opt ')
set @pC = @pC +1;
end
set @pSQL = concat ('select X1.Opt', @pSelect,@pSQL ,@pJoin)
exec(@pSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create function GeneratePermutations (@string nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS @Permutations 
TABLE(
    name nVARCHAR(500)
  )
AS
begin
     declare @SplitedString table(name nvarchar(500))
 
     insert into @SplitedString
     select *
     from string_split(@string,' ')


    declare @CountOfWords as int

    set @CountOfWords = (select count(*) from @SplitedString) 

    ;with cte_Permutations (name, level) as (
       select convert(nvarchar(500), name), 1 as level from @SplitedString
       union all
       select convert(nvarchar(500),splited.name+','+cte_Permutations.name),level+1 
       from @SplitedString splited ,cte_Permutations
       where level < @CountOfWords
    )
    insert into @Permutations
    select  name
    from cte_Permutations
    where level = @CountOfWords
    order by name

    return  
end


select * 
From (
        select 1 id,'a b c' msg
        union all 
        select 2 id,'d e' msg
    ) p  
    cross apply dbo.GeneratePermutations(p.msg)
```