# Querying MySQL for anagrams

Tags: php, mysql, sql, anagram

I have this script:

```
$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($database,$db) or die( "Unable to select database");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

$wordy = "pate";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM $db_table WHERE word LIKE '[pate]' ORDER BY word DESC");
$num = mysql_numrows($query); $i=0; 

while ($i < $num) {
    $word = mysql_result($query,$i,"word");

    echo $word." ";
    $i++;
}
```

`$db_table` contains English words. I want to echo out all possible anagrams; in this case it should echo `tape pate peat`. What query could I use to do this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx <- here is a description

Comment: Good grief. So you're looking of `IS_ANAGRAM` or such like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think first you must re arrange all the letters in the word to form an array

then do a sql query like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM $db_table WHERE word in ($array ) ORDER BY word DESC
```

got another idea :

you can do something like ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM $db_table WHERE word like '%$wordy[0]%' AND like '%$wordy[1]%' AND like '%$wordy[2]%' AND like '%$wordy[4]%' ORDER BY word DESC
```

Froe the comments I could suggest you use

length(word) = strlen($wordy)

Comment: say you rearrange the letter pate using php and store it into an array -> $array

Comment: Hmm seems my idea is bad for words of length > 8 letter.. :(

Comment: the idea is that i dont what to use permutation, im looking for the simplest way

Comment: Are `$wordy[x]` individual letters in the word? That would retrieve way too many words, I'm afraid.

Comment: yes those are individual letters .. Yeah they would return words like "xxxxpatexxxx" so you can put another check for length of word and that would solve your problem .. right ?

Comment: Even with the word length check it wouldn't work for words that have multiple instances of letters, for example "stars" would match words like "start".

Comment: hmm yes.. agreed... Will think and let you know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991729/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-anagrams-using-sql check this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621494/sql-the-most-elegant-way-to-generate-permutations-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify the table that contains the dictionary, run a script that adds a field for each entry that has the word with the letters it contains in alphabetical order. Then you can put the letters in the word you're searching similarly in alphabetical order and look for matches.

Tape, pate and peat would all look like "aept" when in alphabetical order, then you can do

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE alpha = 'aept' ORDER BY word DESC");
```