# How to shuffle search data in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have table with column firstname. I have input for example ABC, the problem here Im not only want to search firstname = ABC, but also CAB or CBA or BAC.

Any idea how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: before we make suggestions, what have you tried?

Comment: Write function, in loop statement write logic.

Answer (score 1):

First create function which gets a string (e.g.'ABC') and returns a table with all permutations of given string (e.g. 'ABC','ACB','BAC','BCA','CAB','CBA')

I have created such a function based on java implementation from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0100__Class-Definition/RecursivemethodtofindallpermutationsofaString.htm) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[permuteString] (@beginStr varchar(10),@endStr varchar(10))
RETURNS @result table (result varchar(10)) 
AS
BEGIN
     declare @i int
     declare @curStr varchar(10)
     if LEN(@endStr) <= 1
           insert into @result select @beginStr+@endStr
     else
           begin
                set @i = 1
                while(@i <= LEN(@endStr))
                begin
                  set @curStr = case when @i > 1 then substring(@endStr,1, @i-1) else '' end
                                + substring(@endStr, @i + 1, LEN(@endStr)-@i)        
                  insert into @result 
                  select * from dbo.permuteString(@beginStr + substring(@endStr,@i,1), @curStr)
                  set @i = @i+1
                end
           end  
    return 
END
```

Now when you have this function, use it along with `in` statement in your query :

```
select columnName
from tableName
where columnName in (select * from dbo.permuteString('',@inputString))
```

You can see more implementations of permutations function here :
[The most elegant way to generate permutations in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621494/the-most-elegant-way-to-generate-permutations-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

### Partial Answer

Seems like a fun problem to solve.  The easy part is splitting the 'ABC' into individual characters and then creating a Cartesian product to combine them into their unique combinations.  The hard part is creating the dynamic SQL to handle the Cartesian product.

Using `abcd` to better illustrate the Cartesian product portion of the example.

```
declare @val varchar(10) = 'abcd'

-- split the string apart
declare @len int = datalength(@val), @i int = 1

select cast(null as int) as id, cast(null as char(1)) as c
into   #temp
where  1=2

while @i <= @len
begin
  insert into #temp
  values (@i, substring(@val, @i, 1))

  set @i = @i + 1
end

-- pull the combinations (need to make this into dynamic SQL)
select a.c + b.c + c.c + d.c as names
into   #combos
from   #temp a, #temp b, #temp c, #temp d
where  a.id <> b.id and a.id <> c.id and a.id <> d.id and
                        b.id <> c.id and b.id <> d.id and
                                         c.id <> d.id

-- check work
select * from #combos

-- use the combos to pull records where the first name matches...
-- select * from [table] where firstname in (select names from #combos)

drop table #temp, #combos
```

Sorry -- don't have the time to figure out the dynamic SQL.  It will be tricky to get it just right.  Each additional character will add exponential bulk to the dyn-SQL.

This does not eliminate duplicate letters like in the name 'Suzanne'.