# INSERT every combination of UNIQUE values without looping

Tags: sql-server

Given 3 values, such as

```
+--------+
| values |
+--------+
|    1   |
+--------+
|    2   |
+--------+
|    3   |
+--------+
```

Is it possible to insert every UNIQUE combination of each value into a table without using a WHILE loop?

For example, the end result would look like:

[image]

It's relatively simple to do this with with nested `WHILE` loops, but I'd like to know if there are any other approaches that could be used.

Comment: Shouldn't the 4th row of data in the end result table have a 3 in the VALUE_2 column?

Comment: @knot22 You're absolutely right! Well spotted, updated now.

Comment: If you can live with them being concatenated with a delimiter instead of a separate column for value, you might want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621494/the-most-elegant-way-to-generate-permutations-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
(
  n int not null
);

insert into @t (n)
values
(1),
(2),
(3);

select * from @t;

select
value1 = t1.n,
value2 = t2.n,
value3 = t3.n
from @t t1
inner join @t t2 on t1.n <> t2.n
inner join @t t3 on t1.n <> t3.n and t2.n <> t3.n;
```

[image]

Comment: Nicely approach! So for every value you have in your data set (say we had 30 values instead of 3), you would need another self-join?

Comment: For this approach, yes.  Are you dealing with 30 values instead of 3?

Comment: I'm dealing with any number of values, really. It's quite a hypothetical scenario. Do you know of a more suitable way given a higher number of values? I still think I prefer this (even with 30 values) over a `WHILE` loop.

Comment: The number of values being dealt with - is that number known before the script executes or is the number of values dynamic with each script execution?

Comment: It would be known before the script executes

Comment: What comes to mind is building dynamic SQL but that might be overkill for this.