# SQL query, How to get entities not used in at least one input group or not used in any groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, relational-division

Let me elaborate with examples.

I have three tables **Entity**(EntityId int), **Group**(GroupId int), and **Mapping**(MapId int, GroupId int, EntityId int).

Let's take a few rows of data.

```
Entity
EntityId
1
2
3
4

Group
GroupId
101
102
103

Mapping
MapId GroupId EntityId
1       101      2
2       102      1
3       102      3
4       103      3
```

I need to select entities that are not used in at least one input group or are not used in any non-input groups.

```
Input-GroupId Output-Entities
   101          1,3,4 ( 2 is mapped with 101)
   101,102      1,2,3,4( 1 is mapped with 102 but not with 101 and 2 is mapped with 101 but not with 102)
   102,103      1,2,4 ( 3 is mapped with both 102 and 103 so it will not be in output.)
```

If there are two input groups. According to the below ven diagram, I need values of all cross-red line areas.

[image: https://www.onlinemath4all.com/venn-diagram-of-a-intersection-b-whole-complement.html]

I tried a few join queries but I am able to get only values that are not used in any groups.

Edit 1:-

```
SELECT distinct EntityId from Entity e
JOIN Mapping map ON e.EntityId != map.EntityId 
JOIN #temp t ON map.GroupId = t.GroupId  order by EntityId
```

I have tried this query. It works fine for
Input-Groups- (101), (101, 102) but does not work for the case (102, 103).

Edit 2:-
A few comments mentioned that the ven diagram is not clear. So this edit.

Let's consider, A(101) and B(102), two groups are provided as input.
[image: Hand made ven diagram]
then all red dotted areas will be considered for the output. The blue pen highlighted area will not be considered.

Comment: what is a non input group?

Comment: Please explain what the Venn diagram areas contain & what A & B label. Dumping a picture that has some vague connection with "not in" is not helpful. LIkely there is a relevant Venn, but this one isn't yet, and it need to involve tables with the same columns & no duplicate rows. PS [Re abuse of such Venn-like diagrams.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642928/3404097)

Comment: [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/367863/3404097)

Comment: For example, ```101          1,3,4 ( 2 is mapped with 101)``` 101 is an input group.102 and 103 are non-input groups. So I need to fetch entities that are not used in 101 and used in 102,103.  @nbk  This is an example with a single input group.

Comment: @philipxy, I have attached ven diagram to explain mathematical/logical relations in the case of two groups as input. Please consider the example, ``` 101,102      1,2,3,4( 1 is mapped with 102 but not with 101 and 2 is mapped with 101 but not with 102)```.    A(101) and B(102). A is linked with Entity 2 and B is linked with Entity 1. Other remaining entities are either linked with other groups(non-input groups) or not linked. 1 or 2 both are not linked with A and B so they will be considered for the output. Also, other entities do not have any linking with A or B so they will be considered too

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. But your comment is unintelligible. Including what A & B are supposed to be & what you put in triple quotes, including what "is mapped with" is trying to say here or what is mapped to what, or what you are trying to say by "linked with" or what "be considered" is trying to say. Again: What are A & B? They need to be sets & if they are sets of (sub)rows they need to have the same columns. And what does the indicated difference set have to do with the query result? Anyway, the diagram says no more than the text A - B, or A EXCEPT B. It's just noise.

Comment: Presumably A & B are "are two input groups", but you don't connect a given A & B pair or the diagram to the base tables, the desired query, a result or the rest of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed list of groups given as input, you want entities that do not belong to *all groups*.

That’s a variant of the relational division problem. I would recommend passing the list of groups as rows using `values()`, and combining it with the entities table. Then we can bring the mapping table with a `left join`, and use the `having` clause to filter on the count of matches.

```
with p as (select * from ( values (101), (102) ) p(groupId) )
select e.entityId
from p
cross join entity e
left join mapping m
    on  m.entityId = e.entityId
    and m.groupId  = p.groupId
group by e.entityId
having count(m.entityId) <> ( select count(*) from p)
```

As an alternative for input, you could have the query accept a comma-separated list of values (hence as a single string parameter), and split it to rows with `string_split` - if that’s easier for the client application to manage.

Here is a **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fdYXZ7G4)**, which yields the expected results for the three test cases of your question:

```
Input (GroupId)   Output (EntityId)
101               1,3,4
101,102           1,2,3,4
102,103           1,2,4
```

Comment: 1st,   Entities that do not belong to all input groups, are linked to other groups or not linked at all.  2nd, I tried your query it says "Invalid object name 'p'.", Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Now, I have also added a SQL query to my question. I have used it but did not get the desired output.

Comment: @HungryWolf: *Invalid object name 'p'.*: my bad, there was a glitch in the query. I fixed it and added a fiddle to my answer. This works as expected, as far as I see.

Comment: Your answer is correct. So I am accepting it. I was also able to do the same with left join. ```select e.entityId
from  Entity e
left join mapping m on  m.entityId = e.entityId
LEFT JOIN #TempGroupIds temp ON m.GroupId = temp.GroupId
group by e.entityId
having count(m.entityId) <> (select count(*) from #TempGroupIds)  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

But i am still unsure about the not input groups

```
SELECT 
  EntityId
FROM Entity WHERE EntityId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT EntityId FROM Mapping )
```

| EntityId |
| --- |
| 4 |

```
SELECT 
  EntityId
FROM Entity e WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Mapping m WHERE m.EntityId = e.EntityId)
```

| EntityId |
| --- |
| 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f3T7McM6)

Comment: Your query gives the entities that are not mapped to any group.

Comment: What you seems to want that automatically all permutation are also calculated, bur math will show you that you have now 6 possibilities , with 4 our you have 24 and so on. Another point usy that you need programming not not SQL for this so that only with a stored procedure you could solve this. So you must think about what do I want

Comment: With a loop SP?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621494/the-most-elegant-way-to-generate-permutations-in-sql-server